# What is difference between 'Before' and 'Until' when they appears in the beginning of sentence?

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between 'until' and 'before'? Eg:

1. Before we have xxx, we can only do yyy...
2. Until we have xxx, we can only do yyy...

Comment: How about "Before 1973 there were dinosaurs" (True). But "Until 1973 there were dinosaurs" (False)